# Rails (or Ruby): Yes/No instead of True/False

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, boolean

I know I could easily write a function and put it in the application controller, but I'd rather not if there is something else that does this already. Basically I want to have something like:

```
>> boolean_variable?
=> true
>> boolean_variable?.yesno
=> yes
>> boolean_variable?.yesno.capitalize
=> Yes
```

is there something like this already in the Rails framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047745/how-to-implement-yes-no-instead-of-boolean-for-certain-cases-in-rails

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No such built-in helper exists, but it's trivially easy to implement:

```
class TrueClass
  def yesno
    "Yes"
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def yesno
    "No"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, that's slicker then what I would have come up with. As far as a rails app is concerned, where would the best place to put this code be? in a file under lib or something?

Comment: I would create a custom initializer in the config/initializer path called "boolean_path.rb". That way, these new methods would be available through the app. Cheers!

Comment: @Eytan I'm new to ruby and rails and I'm trying to stick with convention but I don't know how to create an intializer, can you help me with it?  Basically what would I put in that boolean_path.rb and how can I use it?  What I would like to do is when I create my model, I would like to use t.boolean_yesno instead of regular boolean and have that output Yes or No instead of True or False.  If you prefer I open another question for this let me know.

Comment: Lets answer your question here because it fits in nicely with this question. To create an initializer, all you need to do is add a .rb file in the config/initializers folder and literally copy and paste the above code into it.

Now, whenever you are working with a boolean variable, you can call: my_boolean_variable.yesno and it will return "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Is it likely that redefining True/False Classes will affect other parts of your app and maybe even 3rd party gems? This is being done globally right?

Comment: @CorySimmons It's not super likely unless you choose a method name that conflicts with something else. `yesno` is probably safe-ish.

Comment: At others have said, whilst this *works*, I wouldn't personally advise extending code ruby classes like this, especially for such a trivial use case. I'd opt for a simple helper method like `human_boolean` described below, instead. Or even just doing to conversion in-line if it's for a one-off use case.

Answer (score 57):

There isn't something in Rails.

A better way than adding to the true/false classes to achieve something similar would be to make a method in ApplicationHelper:

```
def human_boolean(boolean)
    boolean ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end
```

Then, in your view

```
<%= human_boolean(boolean_youre_checking) %>
```

Adding methods to built-in classes is generally frowned upon. Plus, this approach fits in closely to Rails' helpers like `raw()`.

Also, one offs aren't a great idea as they aren't easily maintained (or tested).

Answer (score 23):

There is a gem for that now: [humanize_boolean](http://github.com/parabuzzle/humanize_boolean)

Then you just do:

```
true.humanize # => "Yes" 
false.humanize # => "No"
```

It also supports internationalization so you can easily change the returned string by including your translation for en.boolean.yes and en.boolean.no (or any locale you like)

Comment: A gem seems a bit egregious for this, no?

Answer (score 19):

The `humanize_boolean` gem extends the `TrueClass`, `FalseClass` and `NilClass` which is an indirect extension I would prefer to avoid.

I've found this helper with a top level translation is isolated, friendly to change and you can give it anything truthy or falsey:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
  def humanize_boolean(boolean)
    I18n.t((!!boolean).to_s)
  end
end

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  :true: 'Yes'
  :false: 'No'
```

Doing `!!(boolean).to_s` ensures the variables passed to the argument is either a `"true"` or `"false"` value when building the translation string.

In use:

```
# app/views/chalets/show.html.erb
<%= humanize_boolean(chalet.rentable?) %>
```

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you could also do one offs in your views such as:

```
<%= item.bool_field? ? 'yes' : 'no' %>
```

Comment: This isn't very DRY, compared to the other solution and will be difficult to localize.

Comment: No, Jeff, you're absolutely right. I was speaking to *one* offs, and not to *many* offs, and in the case of the latter, a helper would of course be the wiser (and DRY) option, as you point out.

Comment: Perfect! I have a one form app, so I don't care about localization/DRY (yet). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

I love the generalised solutions in the previous answers, but if you want to selectively use a humanised version of your boolean in your views, you could do the following:

I put this into helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def humanize_boolean(value)
    case value
    when true
      "Yes"
    when false
      "No"
    when nil
      "Undefined"
    else
      "Invalid"
    end
  end

end
```

Then from views you can call it as in this example:

```
Published: <%= humanize_boolean(post.published) %>
```