# Replace output of true and false in a view with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, string-formatting

I’ve got a view which evaluates a database table with boolean values. Those fields contain, who thought of it, wether true or false.

I’d like to replace this text with something like Yes and No. Or Ja und Nein. Doesn’t matter. Is there any Rails way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails (or Ruby): Yes/No instead of True/False](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664181/rails-or-ruby-yes-no-instead-of-true-false)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<%= @attribute ? 'Yes' : 'No' %>
```

A nice place to put this might be in the model, so

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  def something_yn
    attribute ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  end
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= @instance.something_yn %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. But I don’t really get it :-D. In my view there’s something like @model.bool_status which outputs false or true. How can I 'translate' this?

Comment: @ulf, I think if you try what DigitalRoss is suggesting you'll see that either way works to get what you want in your View. Google "Ruby ternary operator" to understand what he wrote in the first line. If `@model.bool_status` is 'true', Ruby will evaluate 'Yes'; if false, 'No'. Rails uses `<%= %>` to render the output in the view. `<%= @model.bool_status ? 'Yes' : 'No' %>`

Answer (score 2):

I made a version which preserves original functionality, while allowing customization in similar fashion to how `DateTime.to_s(:style)`.

https://gist.github.com/pehrlich/4963672

```
class TrueClass
  def to_s(style = :boolean)
    case style
      when :word then 'yes'
      when :Word then 'Yes'
      when :number then '1'
      else 'true'
    end
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_s(style = :boolean)
    case style
      when :word then 'no'
      when :Word then 'No'
      when :number then '0'
      else 'false'
    end
  end
end
```

I put this in lib and then include with this line in application.rb:

```
require "./lib/boolean.rb"
```

Comment: It would be great to toy with implementing this with Refinements: http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-refinements-an-overview-of-a-new-proposed-ruby-feature-3978.html