# Why won't my rails app work when pushing to Heroku: "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `toilet_available' for nil:NilClass)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet, maps

I'm building a store locator app in Rails 5 that uses the Open Street Map API and leaflet-rails gem. Everything works as expected in development environment but when I push to Heroku I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message. I created a function where you can sort stores by whether they have a toilet or not and this seams to be where the problem lies. The Heroku logs show the following:

```
2018-09-12T22:02:39.751563+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 624ms (ActiveRecord: 119.5ms)
2018-09-12T22:02:39.706503+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]   Toilet Load (29.5ms)  SELECT "toilets".* FROM "toilets"
2018-09-12T22:02:39.772904+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773276+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     29:                                             <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %> </li>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.772915+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `toilet_available' for nil:NilClass):
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773280+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     30:                                             <li><%= link_to "Add Spaeti", new_user_registration_path %> </li>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773283+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     31:                                     <% end %>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773285+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     32:                                     <li><%= link_to "Spaetis with toilets", stores_path(toilet: Toilet.all[0].toilet_available) %></li>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773288+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     33:                             </ul>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773290+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     34:                     </div>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773292+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]     35:             </nav>
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773336+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123]
2018-09-12T22:02:39.773423+00:00 app[web.1]: [30a84d17-6a5a-4b3d-b21f-ee08babfd123] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2166090761148733231_41993540'
```

When I remove this line from the view the app loads fine: `<li><%= link_to "Spaetis with toilets", stores_path(toilet: Toilet.all[0].toilet_available) %></li>`

What could be causing this error? I've been tearing my hair out for a good few days now...

Store Model:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :toilet

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
    validates :address_line2, presence: true
    validates :address_line3, presence: true
    validates :toilet, presence: true
    # validates :latitude, presence: true
    # validates :longitude, presence: true
    validates :beer_cost, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 10 }
    validates :latitude, :presence => {message: "Not a valid location, please check name address & country fields" }

    def full_address
      [address, address_line2, address_line3].compact.join(', ')
    end
    geocoded_by :full_address
    before_validation :geocode,
      :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.address_changed? }

    def capitalize_name
        name.capitalize
    end

    def capitalize_address
        address.capitalize
    end
end
```

Toilet Model:

```
class Toilet < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :stores
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180814220216) do

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.float "beer_cost"
    t.text "facilities"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.boolean "toilet"
    t.string "address_line2"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "toilet_id"
    t.string "address_line3"
  end

  create_table "toilets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "toilet_available"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Github repo: https://github.com/catsinspacesuits/Spaeti-App

Comment: The error is telling you that it can't find a `Toilet` via `Toilet.all[0]` (because it's nil). Can you gives us a bit more info on what you're trying to do there? What happens if you try: `Toilet.first` instead? Can you confirm there are actually Toilets in the db yet? If not - you may need to put `if Toilet.count > 0` on the end of that line

Comment: Actually... is `toilet_available` a scope on your `Store` model? if so you probably really want to write something like: `Store.toilet_available.first` instead.

Comment: Note: I'm having to guess what you mean as you haven't added any actual code to your question ;)  Could you edit your question and add the `Toilet` and `Store` models as well as the `stores` route from your routes file?

Comment: `stores_path(toilet: Toilet.toilet_available.first)` throws a no method error in development

Comment: `toilet_available` in the Toilet model should have two options "yes" and "no". But neither option shows in the view when I try to select one when creating a new store. This isn't the case in development - I am able to select "yes" or "no" and create the store. I'm wondering if it's some kind of postgres related problem, as everything is working fine in development.

Comment: @TarynEast Have added the code for the models and the link to the repo

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do with the `stores_path` here... in a `path` method, you are creating a URL and with something like `stores_path(toilet: thing)` I'd be expecting you to be passing an actual toilet object in `thing`. Not a string value of an individual toilet (which is what `toilet_available` is), an actual instance of a Toilet object... that's why I'd like to see the relevant routing code :)

Comment: Looking at your routes file it's even simpler than that. you are using the generic `stores` route... you haven't told Rails how to generate a route that takes a toilet object. So it doesn't know what that is for and is just ignoring it. you can write `stores_path` but it literally has no clue what you mean by `stores_path(toilet: anything)`... so even if you go this code not to error - it isn't doing what you think it's doing. You can't pass a toilet to the `stores_path` method unless you specify the toilet in the route.

Comment: Also - if you tell me that creating a Toilet model is breaking instead of selecting yes/no? that confuses me... can you show me the relevant code that does this in the html-form and the controller? Words are ambiguous and while it's clear to you what you mean, it isn't clear to me :)

Comment: Ooookay, eventually found a solution. On the production (pg) side I hadn't added anything into the Toilet table. I needed to run `heroku run rails console` and then `Toilet.create(toilet_available = "yes")` and `Toilet.create(toilet_available = "no")`. Thanks for all the suggestions and sorry for my ambigious and slightly incoherent questions!

Comment: All good! I'm glad you found a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misinterpreted what you were trying to do. I think that even though you are no longer getting the error, you are still not getting the answer you intend to get. You are using a very non-standard way to have a boolean column. On the rails console do this:

```
t = Toilet.first
t.toilet_available
```

and look at the return value. Regardless of "yes" or "no" you are getting a value. So if this:

```
Toilet.all[0].toilet_available
```

is supposed to mean: "get all toilets and take the first one where available = yes" that is NOT what is happening. A DB column defined as the type of `String` with a "yes" or "no" is not a boolean and will not act like one without defining a method to interpret it like:

```
def has_toilet
  self.toilet_available == "yes" ? true : false
end
```

I think what you are getting with your `Toilet.all[0].toilet_available` is "Get all toilets and take the first one of the results and return the text in column toilet_available regardless if that text is `true` or `false`". But if your intent is "get me the first toilet whose availability is `true`" then your code is wrong.

Here is a simple test to use in your development DB where you have plenty of records. In the Rails console do this:

```
puts Toilet.all[0]
puts Toilet.all.first
puts Toilet.where(toilet_available: 'yes').limit(1)
puts Toilet.find_by(toilet_available: 'yes')
```

They may not all return the same result. The pattern of `.all[0]` is IMHO a bad way of getting something out of the DB as it is very ambiguous.

Also do this in the console:

```
Toilet.all.each do |t|
  puts "toilet_available is #{t.toilet_available} and is #{t.toilet_available ? true : false}
end
```

You should see something like:

```
toilet_available is yes and is true
toilet_available is no and is true
```

The point being that in Rails having a text value in a text column results in it being "true". The only way to get a false would be for the value to be `nil`. If `toilet_available` will only ever have two states then a boolean column type would be more appropriate and what other developers will tend to expect. If the value could be three states like "yes", "no", "unknown" then you could use a column with a state machine.

Comment: I don't understand. You say I haven't defined `toilet_available` but then say "you defined it as a text that you are intending to store `yes` or `no`"

Comment: Edited my answer. Still not fully understanding your intent.

Comment: Also reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047745/how-to-implement-yes-no-instead-of-boolean-for-certain-cases-in-rails   and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664181/rails-or-ruby-yes-no-instead-of-true-false