# Output "yes/no" instead of "t/f" for boolean data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

How do I make a query that would return `yes/no` instead of `t/f` (true/false)?

Current solution is:

```
SELECT credit_card_holders.token IS NOT NULL AS premium
```

I found a Ruby solution:
[Rails (or Ruby): Yes/No instead of True/False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664181/rails-or-ruby-yes-no-instead-of-true-false)

But would rather do it in PostgreSQL if possible.

Comment: Do you actually need the sql query to return "Yes" or "No"?  Can't you just use a helper method or model method to translate the boolean to the required string?

Answer (score 12):

Ended up with this:

```
(case when credit_card_holders.token IS NOT NULL then 'Yes' else 'No' end) AS premium
```

Answer (score 7):

by creating custom types also you can achieve this, see the following example

```
create table foo (id int,xid int);
insert into foo values (1,2),(2,3);
```

we have following data

```
id xid 
-- --- 
1  2   
2  3
```

and the following select statements returns boolean value.

```
select exists(select * from foo where xid=4);

exists
boolean
------
f

select exists(select * from foo where xid=3);

exists
boolean
------
t
```

ok now we need to return `YES` and `NO` instead of `t` and `f`, so we can create a custom type like below

```
create type bool2yesno as enum ('YES','NO'); --or whatever you want 'yes','no'.
```

and create a function to convert boolean to the created custom type i.e `bool2yesno`

```
create function convert_bool_to_bool2yesno(boolean)
  returns bool2yesno
  immutable
  strict
  language sql
as $func$
  select case $1
    when false then 'NO'::bool2yesno
    when true  then 'YES'::bool2yesno
  end
$$;
```

now create a `cast` for the newly created type

```
create cast (boolean as bool2yesno )
  with function convert_bool_to_bool2yesno(boolean)
  as assignment;
```

now again try the select statement

```
select exists(select * from foo where xid=4)::bool2yesno ;

exists 
bool2yesno 
----------
NO     

select exists(select * from foo where xid=3)::bool2yesno ; 
exists 
bool2yesno 
---------- 
YES
```

*Reference :* 
[CREATE TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtype.html)
[CREATE CAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createcast.html)
[CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: Note that to output `no` for `NULL` it is need to remove `strict` attribute in `convert_bool_to_bool2yesno` function definition.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way in case true/false is good enough:

```
SELECT (credit_card_holders.token IS NOT NULL)::text AS premium
```

At least it's more readable than t/f!

Answer (score -1):

With this gem [humanize_boolean](https://github.com/parabuzzle/humanize_boolean) you can do so

`true.humanize # => "Yes" 
 false.humanize # => "No"`